# site interaction blocked after keyframes animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

my css animation run well but when the animation is fisnished, i can't interacting with  anchor or another interaction on my website...

```
hr{
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
    z-index: 4;
    -webkit-animation: ligne 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#background{
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, #EFF0FF);
    -webkit-animation: fond 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#logo{
    color: red;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    -webkit-animation: logo 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}




@-webkit-keyframes ligne{

    0%{width:0%;}
    60%{width: 99.9%;}
    80%{width: 99.9%;opacity: 1;}
    100%{width: 99.9%;opacity: 0;}    
}

@-webkit-keyframes fond{

    0%{background-image: linear-gradient(white, #EFF0FF);}
    80%{background-image: linear-gradient(white, #EFF0FF);}
    100%{background: transparent;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo{

    0%{opacity: 0;}
    30%{opacity: 1;}
    80%{opacity: 1;}
    100%{opacity: 0;}    
}
```

I'm only on HTML5/CSS3, so please don't reply solution in JS or other, thanks :).

Comment: Although quite a bit can be done with just CSS https://github.com/i0z/nojsgame, banning js seems like cutting yourself off from lots of potential help...

Comment: yeah i know but i start html/css 5 days ago... i need some more experience for start JS.

Comment: That's what I'm saying though, to make an interactive pure css site like the one in the github repo I linked to requires *expert* knowledge of css, its the kind of thing people do as an experiment or to show off their mad skills. Just use `javascript` to add/remove appropriate css classes with new animations by using event handlers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers
Or to put it another way, its not that interaction is blocked on your site its that your initial animations have finished and you aren't doing anything to trigger more.

Comment: i find a solution, i have set all animation DIV to z-index:-1; at the end of the animation, now i can use my anchor without problem :). like this:         <code>@-webkit-keyframes fond{
    0%{background-image: linear-gradient(white, lightblue);}
    80%{background-image: linear-gradient(white, lightblue);}
    99%{background: transparent;z-index:3;}
    100%{background: transparent;z-index: -1;}
}</code>